# Libgmp3 not present

Tags: compiling, libraries, haskell

I need `libgmp.so.3` to install `GHC`.  However, installing `libgmp-dev` only installs `libgmp.so` and `libgmpxx.so` according to the installed files list.  I have seen elsewhere people using symlinks, but this seems like a bad idea.

I have these related questions:

1. Is this a bug in the GHC build or the Ubuntu library?
2. In either case, I still need `libgmp.so.3`.

How can I obtain these library correctly?

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, there is just a mismatch between the libgmp version that ships with Ubuntu and the libgmp version in the pre-compiled GHC.  The simple way to fix this is to:

1. Install the Ubuntu version of GHC;
2. Download, build, and install GHC from source -- this links it with the correct libgmp;
3. Uninstall the Ubuntu version of GHC;
4. Install the Haskell-Platform that corresponds to the GHC version compiled.

Note that simple does imply fast!